# Call methods from another class in a C# GUI

Tags: c#, user-interface, methods, call

Hi I have a small problem. I have a GUI in C# and a class called 'methods'. Methods provides a variety of well ... methods for my GUI. However for some reason when I try to instanstiate the methods class, I can not call it in my GUI. My code looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        Methoden m1 = new Methoden();
        Parameter p1 = new Parameter();
        m1.InitializeSensors(p1.ISensor);
    }




    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m1. // this does not work
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have declare the `Methoden m1 = new Methoden();` in constructor of Form1 and the scope of the Object m1 is ended so you are not able to access that object outside of constructor you should have to use

```
 Methoden m1=null;
 public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
         m1 = new Methoden();
        Parameter p1 = new Parameter();
        m1.InitializeSensors(p1.ISensor);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the code posted, your `m1` variable is declared and initialized within your `Form1` constructor. This means that the variable will exist only within the scope of the constructor, thus once that your code execution steps out of your constructor, the `m1` variable will cease to exist.

To solve this problem, you would need to move the decleration of the `m1` variable outside the scope of the constructor, like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    Methoden m1;
    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        m1 = new Methoden();
        Parameter p1 = new Parameter();
        m1.InitializeSensors(p1.ISensor);
    }




    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       m1. // this does not work
    }
```